# Menu indentation after full screen

Tags: flv, flash, flvplayback, jwplayer

Using the JW player, streaming flv via rtmp. I am also using the snell.swf skin. When I click on full screen, then return to normal I am seeing the menu for the currently playing item indent. Any ideas what is causing this?

Also sometimes seeing menu items highlighted which are not the currently playing ones. Any ideas here as well?